# PDFBox - Setting Cover Sheet for PDF Portfolio

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am creating a PDF portfolio from scratch using PDFBox 2.0.16.  I create the PDF and add attachments.  Once the attachments are added, I then create the PDF Portfolio.  The following is the code to create the PDF Portfolio/Package.

```
COSDictionary collectionDictionary = new COSDictionary();
collectionDictionary.setName( COSName.TYPE, "Collection" );
collectionDictionary.setName( "PDF Filename", "T" );
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
catalog.getCOSObject().setItem( "Collection", collectionDictionary );
pdfDoc.save( pdfFile );
```

When I open the PDF, the Cover Sheet is a blank page.  I would like the Cover Sheet to be the first attachment in the PDF Portfolio/Package so that when a user opens the PDF, the 1st attachment in the portfolio is viewed.

Comment: Please read this https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreatePortableCollection.java?view=markup

Comment: I followed the code and the PDF portfolio is created and opens in Adobe with the list of embedded files.  However, it opens to the page that reads "Example of a portable collection".  Is there a way for to open the first embedded file when opening the PDF?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What somewhat worked for me (it positioned to this file, as if I had clicked on it in the list) is this:

```
collectionDictionary.setString(COSName.D, "Attachment 1");
```

where "Attachment 1" is the name used in the name tree in [this example](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/CreatePortableCollection.java?view=markup).